# little subtle difference with the filter() function

Tags: python, filter

I was reading the filter() doc at `http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html`. I don't quite get the subtle differences of the results produced by the filter() function shown below.  I tried to make the p & q lists as similar as possible to enhance this subtle differences.

```
>>> p = ("A", "e", "I", "o", "U", "o")
>>> filter(lambda x: x not in ["e", "o"], p)
('A', 'I', 'U')
>>> q = ("Z", "o")
>>> filter(lambda x: x not in ["e", "o"], q)
('Z',)
```

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: I meant to ask why the second filter() produced a result that has a `,` while the first didn't.

Comment: I'll remove the last two lines to make my question more clear.

Comment: Tuple with a single item expressed as: `(item,)` to digtinguish from `(item)` which is just a item surrounded with parentheses. `(item) == item == (item,)[0]`

Comment: @lessthanl0l both the type of first and second filter are same
('a','b') and ('a',) are tuples and hence ('a') is not a tuple and just str

Comment: ah, so ("a", "b", "c") == ("a", "b", "c",)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the `('Z',)` is a tuple and `('Z')` is simply a string enclosed in Parenthesis.

```
print type(('Z',))
# <type 'tuple'>

print type(('Z'))
# <type 'str'>
```

When you say `('Z')`, Python considers it something similar to `(1 + 2)`. It simply evaluates the expression inside that.

But when you put a comma inside that `('Z',)` it considers that as a tuple.

Quoting from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#parenthesized-forms),

> A parenthesized expression list yields whatever that expression list
> yields: **if the list contains at least one comma, it yields a tuple;
> otherwise, it yields the single expression that makes up the
> expression list.**
>
> An empty pair of parentheses yields an empty tuple object. Since
> tuples are immutable, the rules for literals apply (i.e., two
> occurrences of the empty tuple may or may not yield the same object).
>
> **Note that tuples are not formed by the parentheses, but rather by use
> of the comma operator. The exception is the empty tuple, for which
> parentheses are required — allowing unparenthesized “nothing” in**
> expressions would cause ambiguities and allow common typos to pass
> uncaught.

Comment: If you look carefully, this second filter() produced a tuple that has a `,` at the end, unlike the first one.

Comment: @lessthanl0l `filter` doesn't do that on purpose. Since `filter` filters a tuple, result will also be a tuple but as per the python rules, I mentioned in the answer, a single element tuple must have a comma at the end.

Comment: @lessthanl0l Type into the interpreter `tuple(['Z'])` and you will again see that trailing comma in the tuple's string representation. This should show you that what you are seeing is not an aspect of `filter`, but of tuples.

Comment: Brackets == `[]`.  Parenthesis == `()`

Answer (score 2):

As the property of tuples,

```
>>> ('a','b',) == ('a','b')
True


>>> ('a',) == ('a')
False

>>> ('a') in ('a',)
True
```

both the type of first and second filters that you specified(not in mine) are same as ('a','b') and ('a',) are tuples and hence ('a') is not a tuple and just str

```
>>> type(('a','b',))
<type 'tuple'>
>>> type(('a','b'))
<type 'tuple'>
>>> type(('a',))
<type 'tuple'>
>>> type(('a'))
<type 'str'>
```